# How to tell Django to put media (pdf) files urls in sitemap.xml?

Tags: django, media, sitemap

I've put static views and model views in my Django generated sitemap.xml file but i do not know how to tell Django to put all of the media files in to it? I have a hundred of PDF files with seo friendly links and i want them in my sitemap.xml, but as they are not in correlation with any of my models i don't know how to manage this?

EDIT: I almost forgot one important thing - my media (pdf) files are served through CloudFront so even if i manage somehow to list them in my Django Sitemap.xml i'll have additional problem because they have 'something.cloudfront.com' in their url's and not on my web site's url 'example.com'. 
Is this even possible to solve? How does this reflect on SEO?

**SOLVED:** 
@kb, thanks for a great answer! I've used RewriteRule in my htaccess as you suggested in the first part of your answer, and it works fine. 
As of second part, instead of creating model for my media files (which would work just fine, but only downside would be manual adding of every new pdf file) 
i decided to add some lines to my items() method so i could list bucket content and filter pdf files. With that i can have all of my files up-to-date all the time, easily:

```
#sitemap.py
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import re

def items(self):    
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = #'my_access_key_number'
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = #'my_secret_access_key'
        Bucketname = #'my_bucket_name'
        conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('eu-central-1', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, is_secure=False, calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat())
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(Bucketname)
        new_list = []
        regex = re.compile(r'bucketsubfolder/media.*\.pdf$', re.I) #i hold my media files in bucketsubfolder so url is for example somedomain.cloudfront.net/bucketsubfolder/media/somefile.pdf
        for item in bucket.list():
            if regex.match(item.name):
                new_list.append(item.name)
        return new_list
```

Comment: You are not allowed to use external urls in your sitemap (or rather, they won't have the desired effect). I think your best option is to create a path on your site like `/hosted/pdf/xxxx.pdf` that redirects to `cloudfront.com/pdf/xxxx.pdf` or similar using rewrites/location patterns. That way you can use a site URL in your sitemap but still have the browser sent to the cloudfront served content directly.

Comment: OK, i think that could help, 1/2 of the problem solved. Do you have any idea how to programmatically include PDF's in django sitemap?

Comment: I haven't done Django for a long time I'm afraid, but essentially there should be an `items()` in the Sitemap class that returns the contents, so you want to manually add things to that list before returning it. I think you might be able do something similar to what they show in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sitemaps/ by extending `Sitemap` like they do with the `BlogSitemap` class. (Check the heading #sitemap-for-static-views as well.)

Comment: You're right, that's possible, but only downside is that i would have to add them manually.. Thank you for help

Comment: My suggestion is that you make a model to represent them, so you have your hosted PDFs (or other CDN content) as a model, for example called StaticHostedFile and you iterate through all of them in the `items()` section. But it does require you to have all the PDFs in some kind of storage so you can find all the filenames and generate the addresses (but maybe that can be done with a simple CSV-file or other). It can be good to know that you can add "includes" in a sitemap.xml so you might be able to split the site content into two sitemaps (content+pdfs) and include both in `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try as you suggested.

Comment: @kb i have successfully done this task with a little different approach so please write an answer with your suggestions above, so i could accept it and give you the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use external urls in your sitemap (or rather, they won't have the desired effect being indexed by Google as part of your site content).

I think your best option is to dedicate a path on your site like `/hosted/pdf/xxxx.pdf` that rewrites everything to `cloudfront.com/pdf/xxxx.pdf` or similar using mod_rewrite/location patterns/regex.

That way you can use a local site URL in your sitemap but still have the browser sent to the cloudfront served content directly, I think this might even be a good use of the 302 HTTP status code.

In the `Sitemap` class there is an `items()` method that returns what is to be included in the sitemap.xml, and you could create your own class that extends it and adds additional data.

You can either manually add the data hardcoded in the method but I think the preferred option is to create a Model that represents each remote hosted file and that contains the information necessary to output it in the sitemap. (This also lets you add properties such as visibility on a per file basis and lets you manage it via admin assuming you set up a ModelAdmin for it.)

I think you might be able do something similar to what they show in http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sitemaps with the `BlogSitemap` class that extends `Sitemap`. Be sure to check the heading "Sitemap for static views" on that page as well.

My suggestion is that you chose the model approach to represent the files, so you have your hosted PDFs (or other CDN content) as a model called `StaticHostedFile` or similar and you iterate through all of them in the `items()` section. It does require you to index all the current PDFs to create models for them as well as create a new model whenever a new PDF is added (but that could be automated).

It can be good to know that you can add "includes" in a sitemap.xml so you might be able to split the site content into two sitemaps (content+pdfs) and include both in sitemap.xml, for instance:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/original_sitemap.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-07-12T09:12Z</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/pdf_sitemap.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-07-15T08:55Z</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

This still requires local URLs and rewrites as per above though, but it can be a nifty trick for when you have several separate sitemaps to combine. (For instance if running a Django site under one subdir and a Wordpress site under another or whatnot.)